# Deep transform of values in typescript object graphs

Tags: typescript

Given an object graph of arbitrary depth, I would like to transform values at specific "object paths", while mapping the transformed value types correctly.

example:

```js
let object = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 123,
    },
  },
  thing: [
    {
      deeperThing: 'hello',
    },
  ],
}

// i want a to be of type { foo: { bar: string }, ... }
const a = transformAt(object, ['foo.bar'], () => 'object is now a string')
// i want b to be of type { thing: { deeperThing: string[] }[], ... }
const b = transformAt(object, ['thing[0].deeperThing'], (v) => [`${v} world`])
```

I'm most interested in how to handle the type mapping. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this problem is intriguing and the bracket notation for arrays `[0]` is neat and all but it would certainly be far easier if it were `thing.0.deeperThing` instead.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5lzw) is my in-progress solution. It's usable but the only thing wrong with it is that it breaks immensely on arrays or tuples.

Comment: This question is really crazy-bonkers for the type system.   And hidden in this question is the apparent need for multiple paths, incorrect path checking, etc.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9EGMN) meet your needs?  If so I could *maybe* write up an answer for it, but it's probably very fragile and currently depends on some TS4.7 functionality (not by necessity, just for ease).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm impressed by your answers thank you for this. This does seems like a tough challenge. In a way I feel like "it's too complicated" is also a valid answer, but  you've got it working, or pretty close. Happy to accept any of these answers.